# Core Block Columns Attributes for Innerblocks Template

Tags: block-editor

I am having trouble setting the `blockGap` or `blockSpacing` property for my [`core/columns` block](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/tree/master/wp-includes/blocks/columns) which I am using for an [Innerblock template](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/#template).

This is my JSON below.  Everything is working as expected, however, the `blockGap` property for the `core/columns` part is not working.  I am trying both the "spacing" -> "blockGap" property as well as just the "blockGap" property. Should I be defining a different property or is this not yet possible for the block?

```
[
["core/columns",
    {
        "spacing":
        {
            "blockGap": "0px"
        },
        "blockGap": "0px"
    },
    [
        ["core/column",
            {
                "width": "50%",
                "className": "main-block"
            },
            [
                ["core/heading",
                {
                    "level": 1,
                    "content": "Title Goes Here"
                }],
                ["core/paragraph",
                {
                    "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
                }]
            ]
        ],
        ["core/column",
            {
                "className": "secondary-block"
            },
            [
                ["core/cover", [],
                    [
                        ["core/heading",
                        {
                            "level": 3,
                            "content": "A Secondary Heading",
                            "textColor": "white"
                        }]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This example works fine for me...

```
const TEMPLATE = [
['core/columns', {
    verticalAlignment: 'center',
    isStackedOnMobile: true,
    templateLock: 'all',
    width: '100%'
},
    [
        [
            'core/column',
            {
                verticalAlignment: 'top',
                isStackedOnMobile: false,
                templateLock: 'all',
                width: '66.66%'
            },
            [
                ['core/image']
            ]
        ],
        [
            'core/column',
            {
                verticalAlignment: 'top',
                isStackedOnMobile: false,
                templateLock: 'all',
                width: '33.33%'
            },
            [
                [
                    'core/heading',
                    { 'placeholder': 'Add H2 Title...', 'level': 2 }
                ],
                [
                    'core/paragraph',
                    { 'placeholder': 'Add paragraph text...' }
                ],
                [
                    'core/gallery'
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ]
]
];
```

Comment: uh huh.... and where are you setting the `blockGap` or `blockSpacing` value?

Comment: [Core Blocks Reference column columns](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/core-blocks/#column) hope it helps you